# JFrame.setAlwaysOnTop is not working

Tags: java, swing

I have created an SSCCE to show my problem

```
public class TopTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(512, 512);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

This program should create a window that is always on top, however if I run this and then click on another window behind it, the JFrame is sent behind it.

Comment: does this happen when you click any window ?

Comment: That code works on this machine.  Do you have other 'always on top' apps. running?  Note that a Swing GUI should be started on the EDT.

Comment: you mean a window behind it that's from another program/process?

Comment: I run the program in eclipse and when I click the eclipse window, my program goes behind it. Also I dont know if this is linked with the problem. I focus listeners aren't firing any events.

Comment: What platform are you running this on?

Comment: I'm running on Windows

Comment: Working fine on my Windows 8 Machine. It should work on Windows.

Comment: What happens when you print `frame.isAlwaysOnTopSupported()`?

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is that you have another window that is **always on top**.So when you click on that this windows loose the focus and goes back.

One easy way if it is a task which needs this window to be on top and Focusable is to frequently check with a Thread maybe:

```
if(!frame.isFocused()) frame.setFocused(true);
```

Just something to help....

Comment: *"Just something to help...."*  Help *who* exactly?  Having an app. play 'dueling always on top' is no help to the end user.

Comment: I said in the questions comments that I click on the eclipse window, which is not the window on top. Also I don't want to frame to be focused.